# FactoryGirl - attribute with default value based on other object

Tags: factory-bot

I have the following factories:

```rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  skip_create

  sequence :group_name do |n|
    "Group #{n}"
  end

  factory :group do
    name { generate(:group_name) }
  end

  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    group
  end
end
```

But there are cases when I want to have a default for the user group (instead of creating new group for each user). So I try something like that:

```rb
describe User do
  let(:our_group) { build(:group) }
  let(:other_group) { build(:group) }

  before do
    FactoryGirl.modify do
      factory :user do
        group { our_group }
      end
    end
  end

  it "users are created in same group by default" do
    user1 = build(:user)
    user2 = build(:user)
    user3 = build(:user, :group => other_group)

    expect(user1.group).to eq user2.group
    expect(user3.group).not_to eq group
  end

  it "user can attend event if #of users in same group is large enough" do
    user1 = build(:user)
    user2 = build(:user)
    user3 = build(:user)

    expect(user1.can_attend_event?).to be_true
  end
end
```

This however fails with error like:

```rb
 Failure/Error: group { our_group }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `our_group' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner:0x000000042c0110>
```

And the important point is that I don't want to modify many existing statements of `build(:user)` into `build(:user, :group => our_group)`. I wish to have a single place to set this default (for a whole spec or possibly for more).

Is there some way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like:

```
  sequence :group_name do |n|
    "Group #{n}"
  end

  factory :group do
    name { generate(:group_name) }

    factory :default_group do
      name "default group"
    end
  end

  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    association :group, factory: :default_group
  end
```

and then in your test:

```
describe User do
  let(:other_group) { build(:group) }

  it "users are created in same group by default" do
    user1 = build(:user)
    user2 = build(:user)
    user3 = build(:user, group: other_group)

    expect(user1.group.name).to eq user2.group.name
    expect(user3.group.name).not_to eq group.name
  end
end
```

If you really want the instances to match (as opposed to just the name) in the default case you will have to build a default group object and assign it each time you build a user; FactoryGirl is not going to re-use the same instance when it builds the association implicitly.

Comment: I tried that but the problem still persists: each user is created with a different group instance (even though the name is the same - the instance is not).

Comment: Well, the goal is to have the same instance of the group, not just to tweak the test to make it pass. Let's say - there may be complicated more complicated logic behind building users: and it's important to have the users linked to same instance of a group.

Comment: Like the answer says, FactoryGirl's implicit associations don't support that (and frankly in a test I would be hard pressed to believe it is really necessary). If you must have the same instance you have to assign it yourself.

Comment: I added one more example: there is a behaviour which originally didn't depend on group membership. Later it's changed to depends on number of users created in same group instance: this requires fixing many tests. Seems the way to do it is to alter each build/create with ":group => same_group" - I was just curious if there is another way but looks like there is not.

Comment: Actually, looking at your example, I wonder if that might not work if you created `@our_group` as an instance variable instead of using `let`. That's just a guess, however.

Comment: An issue with instance variable is that it's not visible in child contexts and it blocks.